# ScrollView Overlaps content in fragment

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

In this fragment as soon as try to scroll the contents start overlapping on each other.
This fragment opens immediately after a Splash Screen Activity. when I try to input something in first edit text and then scroll at that time all the things overlap on each other. The overlapping takes place only when I try to scroll. Please Help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView_login"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".LoginFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/MarginTop"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launch"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tagline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/tagline"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/Candidate_login"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tagline" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailmobile"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:hint="Enter Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/pass"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailmobile" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passedit"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:hint="@string/pass"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/log_in"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passedit" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/forget_pass"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/log_in" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sign"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/NoAccount" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSignUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:text="@string/signup"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: please share screenshot of what you are getting and what exactly you want here

Comment: done can you help now

Comment: i added your layout in my project ..your scroll is working fine ,...it is not even overlapping in my project..it is working fine

Comment: it is showing problem in some devices like realme 2pro

Comment: Try changing your ScrollView height to wrap_content.

Comment: No @KalanaChinthaka changing to wrap content doesn't help